# is GPUImage available for iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, gpuimage

I got an error message for GPUImage in iOS8 but it works fine in iOS7, so is any one know that GPUImage is available for iOS 8 or not?

Getting this error :

```
Debug-iphoneos/libGPUImage.a file '/Users/xyz/Desktop/mno/project1/Latest/projectDemo/External Library/build/Debug-iphoneos/libGPUImage.a' for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the copy of libGPUImage you have doesn't have armv7s symbols included in it.

You need to recompile, or re-download and then recompile, the GPUImage opensource library from GitHub.  [You can find it here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

GPUImage needs a few other frameworks to be linked into your application, so you'll need to add the following as linked libraries in your application target:

> CoreMedia
>
> CoreVideo
>
> OpenGLES
>
> AVFoundation
>
> QuartzCore